# VSCode Extension API get comment type per language ID

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am creating a extension, where I add more text based on code.

I wanted to add that text as a comment.

Is there anyway of doing that?

Using the VSCode API to get the comment type or a function that automatically comments a string.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Insert a [snippet with a command](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_assign-keybindings-to-snippets) containing the `LINE_COMMENT` or `BLOCK_COMMENT_START` and
`BLOCK_COMMENT_END` variables and the text you want as a comment

Comment: I see, that's a good idea. But how do I know what Comment type to use? Do I need to define a file with all possbilities or does the API provide me?

Comment: AFAIK there is no easy API to find if the current language has a Line or Block comment (you can traverse all extensions and analyze the language configs), you can insert the text, select the text, call `editor.action.commentLine`

Comment: Doesn't just the `insertSnippet` with `LINE_COMMENT`, etc, work for you?  Does it not automatically insert the correct comment characters based on the active text document filetype?  If you really need to get the comment characters for installed language types I can help, but I would expect `insertSnippet` is working for you.

Comment: @Mark not all languages have both types of comment

Comment: Good point, I knew that.   CSS for example.   So I have a couple of extensions that can get the grammar.comments.blockComment or grammar.comments.lineComment for the current language pretty easily or all installed languages.

Comment: @Mark I think it would be handy to have an API that returns the language config properties of the document